# R package tabulizer error

Tags: r, package, failed-installation, tabulizer

I am using macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6. RStudio is Version 1.1.456. 
I wanted to use tabulizer library, but it failed to be installed with the following error message. It used to work before I reinstalled macOS system a month ago.

Nothing I found on Google so far resolved the issue. Someone suggested this has something to do with Java, which I am completely unfamiliar with.

Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I did, and I also tried devtools to download it. Nothing worked